# Kms request automatically increasing on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloud, amazon-kms

KMS requests are continuously increasing on my AWS account. I am on Free Tier package. My monthly quota is 20,000 requests, but in first 7 days, I've used 45 % of it (9000 requests).

Please tell me how to control this number I have no instance running at the time still the requests are increasing. No instance, no KMS keys, no web apps, no deployments, and I don't know why this is happening to me. I tried a lot to search on Google but couldn't find anything helpful.

EDIT: 
First I created an instance and deployed a Django project. After 3 days I terminated that instance. Now I have no services running. In last 2 days, KMS requests count has been increased by 10%.

Comment: Which services are you using?

Comment: First I created an instance and deployed a Django project. After some time I terminated that instance. Now I have no services running. In last 2 days KMS requests count has been increased by 10 %.

Answer (score 3):

KMS is used by a number of other AWS services, and there is also a default key. Some examples of where this can be used:

- Encrypting data of any type
- AWS Certification Manager SSL certs in an ELB/CloudFront

As for encryption, there's encrypted EBS volumes, RedShift data, S3 bucket data, parameters in EC2 Parameter Store, etc. If you still haven't got any idea what is causing the KMS allocation hits you might want to use [CloudTrail to log calls](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/kms/latest/developerguide/logging-using-cloudtrail.html). Note that CloudTrail itself can encrypt data and essentially kill your KMS allocations, and the logs it stores in S3 count against your S3 allocations.

Comment: Hey, Chris, I had two S3 buckets running. I deleted those now. Were these buckets causing an increase in KMS requests or there's something else I don't know?

Comment: @only4 as mentioned you should enable CloudTrail logs (see the link in the answer) and view the logs to see what is calling KMS.

Answer (score 0):

After trying a lot I finally sorted out this by my self.
the problem was a remaining S3 bucket, after deleting those the KMS requests stopped increasing.